# Deserialized Objects Exceeded when pulling send-as permission for mailbox

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I am running this powershell script in order to pull Send-As permissions.

Get-Mailbox -Resultsize Unlimited | Get-ADPermission | ? {($*.ExtendedRights -like "*send-as*") -and -not ($*.User -like "nt authorityself")} | ft Identity, User -auto

I get the error "Deserialized objects exceed the memory quota".  Can someone help me get passed this error?  I don't want to change the maximum output and preferably would like to have it return multiple .csv files if I can work around this error.